# how to make whole item clickable instead of just visible items?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a sidebar containing different items to open different screens. But i am only able to make image and textview clickable not whole item.

```
      _myDrawer() => Drawer(
             child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
             padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
             children: <Widget>[
             DrawerHeader(
               child: _myDrawerHeader(),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: const Color(0xFF0ea0aa),
               ),
             ),
              Container(
                 width: double.infinity,
                 child: GestureDetector(
                     onTap: () {
                       Navigator.push(context,
                           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                         return TermNCondition();
                       }));
                     },
                     child: Row(
                       children: <Widget>[
                         _drawerItem('images/ic_tc.png', 'Terms & 
                           Conditions'),
                         _addDivider(Colors.grey)
                       ],
                     ))),
          ],
         ));




           _drawerItem(String imagePath, String title) => 
        Row(children: <Widget>[
         Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 8, top: 10, 
           bottom: 10),
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(imagePath),
          height: 22,
          width: 22,
         ),
        ),
       Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 10, bottom: 
        10),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: _textStyle,
         ),
         ),
        ]);


         _addDivider(Color color) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
       child: Divider(
        height: 1,
        color: color,
     ),
   );
```

Click on icon and text"Terms & Conditions" is working fine, but whole view is not clickable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw3Kc.png)

Comment: did you try swapping GestureDetector and Container?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Wrap GestureDector with FittedBox. this widget helps you for scaling child to parent's size

```
 _myDrawer() => Drawer(
         child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
      // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
         padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
         children: <Widget>[
         DrawerHeader(
           child: _myDrawerHeader(),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: const Color(0xFF0ea0aa),
           ),
         ),
          Container(
             width: double.infinity,
             child: GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {
                   Navigator.push(context,
                       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                     return TermNCondition();
                   }));
                 },
                 child: FittedBox( //
  fit: BoxFit.cover  // here is the magic
  child:Row(
                   children: <Widget>[
                     _drawerItem('images/ic_tc.png', 'Terms & 
                       Conditions'),
                     _addDivider(Colors.grey)
                   ],
                 ))
     )),
      ],
     ));




       _drawerItem(String imagePath, String title) => 
    Row(children: <Widget>[
     Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 8, top: 10, 
       bottom: 10),
    child: Image(
      image: AssetImage(imagePath),
      height: 22,
      width: 22,
     ),
    ),
   Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 10, bottom: 
    10),
    child: Text(
      title,
      style: _textStyle,
     ),
     ),
    ]);


     _addDivider(Color color) => Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
   child: Divider(
    height: 1,
    color: color,
 ),
 );
```

For more information about this Widget, please look for docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html)

Comment: It made text and image to take full space and it is not looking as required. Also outside text and image it is still not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change the order of container and GesterDetector. I tried and it is working pretty well.

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return TermNCondition();
                  }));
            },
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _drawerItem('images/ic_tc.png', 'Terms & 
                      Conditions'),
                      _addDivider(Colors.grey)
                ],
              ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: yes, i have done that. It is not working for me. Still similar problem.